# Unix/Mac OS X: Use file list to copy files and folder keeping the directory structure

Tags: macos, bash, unix, copy

I have a plain text file containing names of hundreds of files with path relative to a home directory (can be made absolute path, if needed) in various sub-directories. The home directory contains multiple directories, and thousands of files. I need to create another directory copying the files in the list, while maintaining their directory structure in the destination.

Example:

Source folder:

```
/home/a/
    file1.jpg
    file2.jpg
    file3.jpg
/home/b/
    file4.jpg
    file5.jpg
    file6.jpg
```

File List: (plain text, in /home/)

```
./a/file2.jpg
./b/file5.jpg
```

Expected Result:

```
/home/dest/a/
    file2.jpg
/home/dest/b/
    file5.jpg
```

Tried cp with various modifications from various questions on stackoverflow, but got a flat folder structure in the result every time.

Using `bash` on OS X Terminal

Please tell how this can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rsync`:

```
rsync --relative --files-from file-list.txt /home /home/dest
```